# 1-Dimensional normal distribution in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, normal-distribution

I have a population along with its mean on x-axis and standard deviation. Assuming it is unimodal, how do i create a normal distribution of this population.

I was able to get the same for 2-dimensional by using the following logic,

```
(pop1) * exp (-0.5 * ( x1 ^ 2 + y1 ^ 2)) / (2 * pi * sd-pop1 ^ 2)
```

so i thought by just replacing/removing y, it should work. But i am not really sure if the output is correct.

Appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not really clear what you want here. Are you trying to assign a variable (eg height) to each turtle and want it to have a normal distribution? In which case you can use NetLogo's random generators. Or do you already have a variable and you want to plot it to see if it's a normal distribution (which is what is suggested by your reference to x-axis)?

Comment: @JenB: It is a patch variable. I have a population with one mean i.e. a unimodal sample of lets say 100 which i want to distribute normally across the patches. x and y in the above equation are the standardized positions of each of those 100 entities in the population. Assume i have 100 candies which has a hypothetical mean position. I want to distribute them over the patches in a manner which mirrors the normal distribution. So that after they are distributed i have 3 kids who move in a way i define. I want to see how many candies each kid has accumulated after some time.